# How to structure a database with Firebase

Tags: database, firebase

I'm in the process where I need to store data under a specific users account with Firebase. I'm fairly new working with the backend and I'm primarily looking for a second option before I start typing away.

**This is how I currently have it structured:**

```
Providers
    City
       Cincinnati 
          Company 1 
             Jobs
             History
          Company 2 
             Jobs 
             History
       Columbus 
          Company 1 
          Company 2
```

My thought is it would be better to have each company listed within a specific city node when a user is requesting from that city. However, if the city was at the first level then we'd have to go through the city first. But instead of having the city at the higher level we can store the cities their in under the companies node essentially in an array.

**So here's the user flow:**

The user makes a request based on their location (city). The provider accepts that specific job which moves into the 'jobs' node. Once the job is complete it then moves into their 'history' node.

**My question:**

Should I keep the structure as is or place the city within the companies node?

Comment: From personal experiance I would not recommend this method. It will save you many headaches if you have a provider object with the city included as an attribute. Firebase does not have the same query abilities as sql statements. It is very possible to acheive a working product with your schema, but remember firebase is great because you work with objects. Right now you are designing a relational db in an oodb. To set an example you can work off of here, build this small setup like you have, and then try to pull the history from a specific city. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is right, as city is your primary key in this case, since a company has a city, you will need to specify first the city where you want to pull companies from. I assume that this structure is the right way to go to solve your problem.

If your parent node is not City and just the name of the cities you will end up with a lot of children in your main tree, and that is what you don't want, you want to structure your database in order to do it readable when data is big enough.

PS: Think in scalability, if you think this way you end up with a good organized database, now, as you are doing it it's OK, but if you have another doubt, think in this way to improve your structure.

Comment: Great feedback! Do you think the current way is scalable if a specific company operates in other cities? They may charge differently depending on a city.